# Convertir texto en una tupla o lista (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola me gustaría convertir un texto en una tupla o lista. El texto lo e sacado de aquí:

```
import os
passwd=os.system("cat /etc/passwd | tail -1")
```

Ahora que tengo la variable passwd con el texto que quiero, ¿Como lo convierto en una tupla o lista?

Answer (score 2):

El primer problema es que `os.system` no captura la salida estándar por lo que `passwd` solo tendrá el valor de retorno del comando, un `0`  en caso de éxito.

Una forma es usar [`os.popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.popen):

```
import os

with os.popen('cat /etc/passwd | tail -1','r') as p:
    lines = p.readlines()
```

Con esto lo que logras es capturar la salida y tener en la variable `lines` la lista completa de lineas de la salida estándar del comando ejecutado, si bien en tu ejemplo solo deberías tener una sola línea (por el `tail -1`). Luego para convertir cada linea en una tupla, solo restaría usar el método `split()` indicando el separador de campo, en este caso `:`.

```
for l in lines:
    tupla = l.split(":")
    print(tupla)
```